# Strange behavior on cookie domain

Tags: asp.net, cookies, forms-authentication

Background:

- AspNet web app / C# 3.5
- IIS7
- VS 2010
- Windows 7

When user is authenticated, we create a cookie, this way:

```
var cookieASP = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(user.Id, true);
cookieASP.Domain = "x.y.local";
```

Yes, `domain` is hard coded for this example.

Using cookies viewer extensions in Firefox 11, I can see that `domain` of cookie is : `.x.y.local`, with a leading `.`. I know that it allows shared cookie between `w.x.y.local` and `q.x.y.local`. Ok.

But, when user clicks on disconnect, he is not kicked out...

```
 var cookieAsp = System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(u.Identifiant, true);
 cookieAsp.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10);
 Response.Cookies.Set(cookieAsp);
 FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

And with debugger we can see that `cookieAsp.Domain` is null. And cookie is not removed from browser's cookies.

If I edit cookie domain (directly from browser), and set its domain to `x.y.local` **without** the leading `.`, cookie is deleted and user disconnected.

I don't understand why this `.` is added, and why it is not well understand by the browser.

**EDIT (major importance I guess)**: we are doing such way because if we don't set `domain`, then IE8 (only 8) can't understand our cookie...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to remove a cookie, you have to specify the cookie with the **exact** domain of the cookie you want to remove.  The cookies domain is not sent by the browser on a request, so you will always get a null value when you try to inspect it within a debugger session.

So before `Response.Cookies.Set(cookieAsp);` add `cookieASP.Domain = "x.y.local";`.